# How can I scale an image without blurring?

Tags: android, image-processing, bitmap

I'm trying to scale a tiny image (something like 20x40 pixels) to an arbitrarily large image. I'm doing the scaling by setting the ImageView.scaleType property, but while it does scale the image, it fades from one original pixel color to the next, creating a large blurry version of the image.

Here's some context for the question. I'm trying to create an old school 16-bit style game for Android. I want to store the sprites/etc as tiny files, and then scale them larger depending on the user's screen size. That way, I don't have to create a ton of different images at different sizes for each sprite. Right now I'm just working on a proof of concept, so I'm trying to scale a tiny 20x40 image file to the size of the entire screen.

*edit: I figured out how to use the method Reflog recommended. However, it still does some fading, just far less than the default algorithm.

*edit2: Got it! I had to turn anti-aliasing off

*edit3: This mysteriously stopped working for me, and I found another place where dithering/auto scaling needed to be disabled. Added the options lines.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setDither(false);
    paint.setAntiAlias(false);

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inDither = false;
    options.inScaled = false;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.tinyimg, options);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, new RectF(getLeft(), getTop(), getRight()/2, getBottom()/2), paint);
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you want nearest-neighbor scaling. Not familiar with Android development, but you could try to search the docs for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
paint.setDither(false);
g.drawBitmap(img, src, dst, paint);
```

to use NN scaling, this will reduce blurring, but also will reduce the quality of the scaling.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm completely new at Android development, so I'm trying to figure out how to use what you told me. I had previously been using Xml to put an ImageView into a Layout, but now I'm trying to do it via code so I can use the paint object. I'll have to continue this tomorrow. Is that "g" variable a Canvas?

Comment: Yep, that's a Canvas. Use this code in overriden protected void onDraw(Canvas g).

Comment: Hmm, apparently comments aren't the place to continue a discussion on this site, so I added it to the original question

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this code can help you:

```
/**
 * @param bitmap Bitmap original
 * @param finWid width of the new Bitmap (width of the cut)
 * @param finHei height of the new Bitmap (height of the cut)
 * @param angulo angle of rotation in degrees
 * @param sx scale X
 * @param sy scale Y
 * @param tx Translate X
 * @param ty Translate Y
 * @param config {@link Config} of the new Bitmap
 * @return {@link Bitmap} transformed
 */
public Bitmap createTransPixBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int finWid, int finHei, float  angulo, float sx, float sy, float tx, float ty, Config config){

    return Bitmap.createBitmap(createTransPixArray(bitmap, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), finWid, finHei, angulo, sx, sy, tx, ty), finWid, finHei, config);

}

public int[] createTransPixArray(Bitmap bitmap, int width, int height, int finWid, int finHei, float angulo, float sx, float sy, float tx, float ty){

    float scaWid = width*sx;
    float scaHei = height*sy;

    int[] ori = new int[width*height];
    bitmap.getPixels(ori, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);

    bitmap.recycle();
    bitmap = null;
    System.gc();

    return transformPix(ori, width, height, scaWid, scaHei, finWid, finHei, angulo, tx, ty);
}

/**
 * Core function for apply scale, translate and rotation (cut the image if you want too)
 * @param ori original color array
 * @param wid original width
 * @param hei original height
 * @param scaWid scaled original width
 * @param scaHei scaled original height
 * @param finWid width of the new Bitmap
 * @param finHei height of the new Bitmap
 * @param angulo rotation in degrees
 * @param tx Translate X
 * @param ty Translate Y
 * @return int[] of colors
 */
private int[] transformPix(int[] ori, int wid, int hei, float scaWid, float scaHei, int finWid, int finHei, float angulo, float tx, float ty){

    int[] fin = new int[finWid*finHei];

    double sin = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angulo));
    double cos = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angulo));

    int dx = (int)((scaWid-finWid)/2);
    int dy = (int)((scaHei-finHei)/2);

    /* No se como explicar esto, solo puedo decir que el proceso de escalado es en sentido inverso
     * escala, rota, translada y corta, todo al mismo tiempo :D
     */
    for(int y = 0; y < finHei; y++){
        for(int x = 0; x < finWid; x++){
            int tempX = (int)Math.floor(((x+dx-((float)scaWid/2))*((float)wid/scaWid))+0.5f-tx);
            int tempY = (int)Math.floor(((y+dy-((float)scaHei/2))*((float)hei/scaHei))+0.5f-ty);

            int tempRX = (int)Math.floor(((cos*(float)tempX)+(sin*(float)tempY))+0.5f+((float)wid/2));
            int tempRY = (int)Math.floor(((cos*(float)tempY)-(sin*(float)tempX))+0.5f+((float)hei/2));

            if((tempRX >= 0 && tempRX < wid) && (tempRY >= 0 && tempRY < hei))
                fin[x+(y*finWid)] = ori[tempRX+(tempRY*wid)];   
        }
    }

    ori = null;
    return fin;
}
```

This function just scale the color array (if you don't want the extra features):

```
private int[] scale(int[] ori, int wid, int hei, int finWid, int finHei){

    int[] fin = new int[finWid*finHei];

    for(int y = 0; y < finHei; y++){
        for(int x = 0; x < finWid; x++){
            int temp = (int)(x*(wid/finWid))+((int)(y*(hei/finHei))*wid);
            fin[x+(y*finWid)] = ori[temp];
        }
    }

    return fin;
}
```

I hope this is useful, and I gladly would appreciate some advice for improving this code.